# How to execute Oracle Store procedure and get resultset from ref_cursor in hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jakarta-ee, stored-procedures

I have a oracle Store procedure where is two in parameter varchar2 type
one **ref_cursor** out parameter  and one number out parameter how to call 
the procedure using hibernate **without obtain JDBC connection from Session object**.

Comment: there are plenty of ways available on google. did you faced any issue with searched result?

Comment: ref cursor is a cute.

Comment: my point was how do i get the resultset from ref_cursor , I am using hibernate 4 and its easy to get the jdbc connection(I have to write extra 3 lines ) But I think There is another way without using jdbc connection

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is an Object-Relational mapping tool, designed to act as a bridge between the OO and Relational paradigms. It's not just a convenience wrapper around JDBC. As such, it's not designed to work with stored procedures.

You can do it, if you really must, using native queries.

Example:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
  "CALL GetStocks(:stockCode)")
  .addEntity(Stock.class)
  .setParameter("stockCode", "7277");
```

Borrowed from http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/

I would recommend instead using MyBatis - this is designed as a convenience wrapper around JDBC, and maps SQL result sets to your domain objects.

http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/

Comment: i want to get the resultset (list) from the OracleTypes.CURSOR without using jdbc connection

Comment: MyBatis can do that. Note that all java persistence frameworks use JDBC under the hood, so you'll still be using it, just not directly.

Comment: Then if i use all  procedures   in my project then why would i use hibernate? I should use normal jdbc instead of bulky hibernate Am i right?

Comment: Yes - if you interact with your database mostly through procedures, then Hibernate would be overkill. Hibernate likes to interact with the database through SQL statements it generates and executes when needed, and most of that is abstracted away from the developer, when you call getters and setters on persistent objects. With procedures, you are still maintaining tight control on the database calls, so Hibernate is not the best choice here.